# Console.ReadLine().Split (',') does not work

Tags: c#

I have the simple snippet of my C# project below.

```
char[] Delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
string[] Input = Console.ReadLine ().Split (Delimiters);
Console.WriteLine (Input[0], Input[1]);
```

I only seem to be getting Input[0]. I've checked on Microsoft's page for splitting strings and various other sources and from what I can tell this SHOULD work.

Comment: What is the input and expected output

Comment: test,test would be my simple input. It should split the two into seperate "test" 's.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string format, object arg0)` will only include the second argument in its return value if the first argument includes a format specifier such as `{0}`

Comment: I've also tried printing them seperately on different lines. I get NullReferenceException for the second.

Comment: One breakpoint might be all you need.

Answer (score 3):

Your [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) method is incorrect. There is no overload that takes in multiple strings and outputs them all individually. Instead, you can format or manually concatenate the strings and pass that into the `WriteLine` method.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", Input[0], Input[1]);
```

Comment: You could actually simplify the format to `Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", Input)`

Comment: Just a short notice, calling `String.Format` is not necessary, because Console.WriteLine has an according overload. `Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", Input[0], Input[1])` will do the same.

Comment: @derpirscher - Good call! Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it to separate lines

```
using System.Linq;

char[] Delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
string[] Input = Console.ReadLine().Split(Delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Input.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```